# Cómo usar GIT en Android Studio mediante SSH con claves privadas?

Tags: android, git

Llevo varios días leyendo e investigando sobre el uso de GIT sobre SSH usando claves privadas en Android Studio pero hasta ahora no he logrado hacer que funcione.

He intentado iniciar un repositorio desde 0 usando las herramientas de control de versiones de Android Studio, también hacerlo primero mediante GIT Bash y luego solo realizar los add, commit, tag y push desde Android Studio.
He intentado cambiar de nombre la clave privada, usar archivo conf para SSH y modificarlo de muchas maneras, incluso he probado con varios servidores GIT incluyendo uno propio.
Lo he intentado con GITHub, Bitbucket, Asembla, GITLab y nada de nada, simplemente el uso de GIT mediante claves privadas no funciona...

Tengo Android Studio 2.2.3 y no se si tenga soporte nativo para uso de claves privadas pero en muchos foros y preguntas de otras ramas de StackOverflow mencionan que si se puede hacer, ya seguí los pasos de muchas de estas respuestas y hasta intenté desde varias computadoras con Android Studio recién instalado, tanto con la versión 2.2.2 y la 2.2.3 pero sigo igual.

Actualmente utilizo Windows 7 SP1 x64 y Windows 10 Home x64, mi versión de GIT es 2.12.0.windows.1, mis claves públicas están correctamente agregadas a los servicios GIT, de hecho si utilizo GIT Bash para hacer los push si puedo hacerlo sin ningún problema, es solo con Android Studio que no he logrado que funcione.

Alguien que sepa como hacerlo, o que me oriente un poco en que podría hacer para que esto funcione por favor, lo único que no puedo hacer es usar claves sin contraseña pues las claves las proporciona la empresa y nunca usan claves sin contraseña.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ya agregué la información que faltaba

Comment: He escrito este pequeño tutorial. A mi me ha funcionado muy bien. Espero sea útil. [Tutorial GitLab con Android Studio](https://gitlab.com/edwardcaceres/tutorial-gitlab-android-studio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buenas.

El proceso para usar Git en Android Studio mas o menos como este.

- Crear un proyecto en AE [Android Studio]
- Activar el versionado de código en VCS/Enable version control integration. Seleccionar Git como sistema.

  [image: img1]

  Entonces se activa la ventana de VCS en la barra inferior.

  [image: img2]
- Configura tu usuario y tu email

  [image: img3]

  > git config --global user.name "nombre"
  >   git config --global user.email e@mail.com
- Añade prepara los archivos para el primer commit `VCS/git/add` y luego haz commit `VCS/commit changes`.

  [image: img4]
- Crea el repositorio en Github. Luego copia los comandos de la seccion `…or push an existing repository from the command line`

  [image: img5]

  Luego escribe el segundo comando

  [image: img6]

  > git remote add origin git@github.com:usuario/repositorio.git
  >   git push -u origin master

  Esto debería darte un error como el siguiente:

  > Permission denied (publickey).
  >   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  >   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  >   and the repository exists.

  Esto es por que no hay clave publica en Github. Entonces:

  Abrir una terminal de git Bash y Generar el par de claves

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "mye@mail.com" -f /c/Users/User1/.ssh/id_rsa
  ```

  [image: img7]

  Luego obtener la clave publica y agregarla a Github.

  ```
  cat /c/Users/User1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  ```

  Usar push de AE en `VCS/git/Push`, entonces solicita agregar el host remoto y la contraseña de la clave.

  [image: asd]

  Luego de eso debería poder usar git normalmente.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Rayos, pasa que soy un programador ciego, entonces no se en que momento aparece ese popup del control de versiones... de casualidad sabes ssi hay un atajo de teclado para moverme a ese popup o como puedo buscarlo en el mapa de shorcuts para agregarlo o modificarlo?, no he podido comprobar si esto soluciona el problema por lo mismo...

Comment: Todas las opciones aparecen en la barra de menú principal `File - Edit - [...] - VCS - Windows - Help`. En VCS es la primera opción me parece :P

Comment: Si, pero mencionas que al momento de hacer push sale un popup donde aceptas el host y configuras la contraseña para la clave privada, y es ese popup el que no encuentro como enfocar con el lector de pantalla. Ya busqué por toda la página de accesibilidad en aAndroid Studio oficial y no encontré nada... creo que alguien me había dicho que era con alt y el acento grabe pero tengo teclado español y no se donde esté esta tecla o cual sea su equivalente.

Comment: Creo que es `VCS/Git/push` (ctrl+mayus+K).

Comment: mmmm... pues ya probé con eso y si me abre la ventana para revisar el commit, las tags y todo eso, pero al momento de darle en el botón de push no hace nada, o al menos el lector de pantalla no dice nada, simplemente se cierra la ventana del push pero no dice nada más, por eso quería saber si hay algún popup donde te de la salida del push o donde tengas que poner la contraseña porque no puedo saber ni cual es la salida del GIT, algo como cuando das alt + 0 cuando compilas.

Comment: Debería salir un popup preguntando la contraseña justo después de hacer push. Si ya ingresaste la contraseña o ha habido algun error deberia salirte en el log de la pestaña de version control (ALT + 9), desde esa pestaña usas ALT+DERECHA para navegar hasta la que dice Console. Esta subpestaña muestra toda la historia del proceso de control de versiones, incluidos los errores. Recuerda que tienes que tener commits pendientes para hacer push.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he conseguido aunque es una pasada porque el popup desaparece si presionas alguna flecha o alt, al menos desaparece cuando se usa lector de pantalla y el modo de accesibilidad en Android Studio, comento para que quede documentado esto.

Comment: La verdad te recomiendo usar la terminal de git, yo suelo usarla mas que lo plugins de los entornos de desarrollo. La terminal te entrega todas las opciones sin ninguna limitación (generalmente las interfaces obvian algunas cosas). Ademas las interfaces cambian mucho según el IDE, ademas de Android Studio, Visual Studio, Net Beans, Eclipse, Sublime text, Source tree, Git Kraken y muchos entornos mas tienen interfaces visuales para git, pero son todas diferentes. :P

Comment: Eso es cierto, siempre había usado la terminal de GIT pero para este proyecto quise utilizar el plugin de Android Studio... al final si me da demasiadas molestias regresaré a la terminal.